# How can I zoom in on a specific region?

Tags: plotting, functions

I made this plot with Mathematica but it's hard to see the region around the cirtial point -1 + 0j.
Is there any way to zoom the region?

```
func = (10 (s + 1)^2)/s^3;
NyquistPlot[func, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always implement your own poor's man zoom.

[image]

Code

```
func = (10 (s + 1)^2)/s^3;
Manipulate[
 NyquistPlot[func,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1, 0}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-xrange, xrange}, {-yrange, yrange}}
  ],
 {{xrange, 44, "x range?"}, 10, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{yrange, 10, "y range?"}, 10, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {xrange, yrange}
 ]
```

Feel free to modify and change range as needed.